# How to layout C++ code: namespaces and similar file names in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, layout, namespaces, directory

This is more of a general question as I have found relatively little information on the net on how to best organize source code.

The way I currently have laid out my code is to have one project in VS compiling a lib, and then two console application projects on top of that, one for unit tests and one to execute the code in the lib.

In the main project, I have a folder called src containing my src code. This source code is then structured into various folders, each holding .h and .cpp files. File names match class names. Folders match namespaces, so every folder is in its own namespace.

I thought this was quite a sensible approach, until I discovered that visual studio 2010 hickups under this approach if two .cpp files have the same name (albeit in different folders and namespaces), because all .obj files are placed into the same temp directory (Debug or Release).

This has led me to wonder, as surely the point of maintaining lots of namespaces and sub-namespaces would be to enable you to have identically named classes and hence files. Some google-ing turned up the solution to individually select conflicting files and place the .obj file into a different place, but some hint at worse performance, and it does seem a bit of an odd approach.

So I am just wondering, is this not a sensible layout? Or do people usually compile each folder into a static library and then link those? Or do you just maintain different filenames? Do you then keep on matching filenames to class names? Because if you do, you wouldn't really need sub-namespaces either, as the whole project could just be in one namespace...

I wonder, I ponder... not sure if this question is concrete enough. I guess my immediate question (assuming the layout is somewhat sensible) is how to get around the conflicting obj files? I am just thinking of renaming the files while maintaining the class names. But I don't like that solution so much.

Thanks (sorry for long question)

P.S. the source folder should be compatible with gcc under linux

Comment: If you have many (or indeed I would say any) nested namespaces, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Neil: With `detail` namespaces as an exception maybe, though that should be left to library coder.

Comment: Its not just Visual Studio 2010. Most IDEs will hiccup if given identical source file names as they all build their intermediate files to a common location ( Project/Debug usually ). This means that any duplicately named source files will compile to the same .obj file and overwrite each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE's usually let you arrange your files logically. (Visual Studio and XCode at least both let you create heirachal groups to arrange your source files, that does not correspond to the locations on disk of the files).

Because most IDEs compile all the source files to a common intermediate folder for the linking step any identically named source files can generate a conflict, where the second file to compile overwrites the .o or .obj of the previous compile.

As such, I've tended to go with a pragmatic approach: All the files for a single target (static library, dylib, exe) are contained in a single folder. Platform specific, or feature specific files, are places in specific sub folders so it becomes easy to rebuild a project for a different platform/configuration by simply adding (or removing) a folder of files at a time. Which really (in hindsight) seems to be the most useful way of using the filesystem effectively.

Rather than creating a deep sub structure, each time a single library becomes too cumbersome, I split off a new static library.

This maps well to the basic project structure IDEs such as Visual Studio and XCode tend to imply as best practice with their wizards: A Project folder, containing multiple target folders, each target folder containing its source files.

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind. As to my current problem, for those who care, I settled as a quick fix on a compromise. I keep header file names identical to class names, and change conflicting cpp file names, e.g. by appending namespace initials to the front of the name.

Answer (score 0):

I set

```
    Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Output File Name
```

to

```
    V:\%(Directory)$(PlatformName)_$(ConfigurationName)_%(Filename).obj
```

for OBJ files to end up next to the sources assuming the project lies on drive `V` (no idea whether there is a macro for it, yet).